# I found these parts but cannot find the set(s) they go to - one is largely tan, others are black and greys

Tags: set-identification

I found these parts but cannot find the set they go to.
Can anyone help identify the sets they belong to?

[image: one is largely tan, others are black and greys]

Answer (score 10):

- The upper left assembly with the [Tan Tile, Modified 4 x 4 with Studs on Edge](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6179&colorID=2&in=A)
  is from set # [75974: Bastion](https://brickset.com/sets/75974-1/Bastion)

[image: 75974: Bastion]

- The upper right assembly is from set# [75322: Hoth AT-ST](https://brickset.com/sets/75322-1/Hoth-AT-ST)
  [image]
- The bottom left assembly is from set# [75035: Kashyyyk Troopers](https://brickset.com/sets/75035-1/Kashyyyk-Troopers)
  ][4
  [image: ]]
- The bottom right assembly with [Dark Brown Wedge 6 x 8 Cutout with Alien Skull in Black Circle Pattern (Sticker)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=32084pb008&colorID=120&in=A) is from set # [70228: Vultrix's Sky Scavenger](https://brickset.com/sets/70228-1/Vultrix-s-Sky-Scavenger)
  [image]